# CSS make div streamlined from all sides

Tags: html, css

I need to make layout like on picture related, the difficult part is, in this big centered div rounded with another divs from all sides. Masonry plugin can make only cornered stamp divs, but not centered. So, how can I implement this?
[image]

Comment: `position: absolute;` is the only thing you can use here

Comment: but if i set center div's position to absolute then other divs wont float it.

Comment: What do you mean by won't float it?

Comment: first align your center div then try to align other div's

Comment: @Mr.Alien I meant "will not wrap around"

Comment: @Nikita I still don't understand what you are saying but I can make this easily

Comment: @Mr. Alien, sorry for my English, so, I said that other divs will not wrap around div with absolute position, is it true?

Comment: @Nikita check this site  http://www.31daysofwindows8.com/

Comment: @Navi that site is wide fail

Comment: @Ms.Nobody check the site alignment

Comment: @Navi, thx but all of divs on this site have with pre-defined height and width.

Comment: @Nikita So in you are expecting all width and height depends on content?i mean dynamic?  why?

Comment: @Navi, because I have some random text in divs, that should wrap around centered div.

Comment: then you can also get the content height and width ryt?

Comment: @Nikita You can keep all the divs with `position: absolute;` and need to set top, left, right and bottom for each which will be tedious process and shabby way to do ...

Comment: @Mr. Alien, but that divs doesn't have pre-defined heights.

Comment: Please post the html code. So I can help you.

Comment: Nice picture, but this is not a programming question. It's more effective that you constult an Agency specialized in Webdesign with your conceptual design.

Comment: I don't get why are people down voting this question, I think it's interesting. And yes it is a matter of coding. I will try something later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just written a kind of extension for the Isotope plugin to enable stamps in random locations. It works quite well, but two stamps can still overlap (have to fix that ;)). Check out the code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XS74t/

The way to use it: give your item the `.stamp` class and add the position as a html5 data element:

```
<li class="item" data-grid-pos='{"x": 2, "y": 1}'>
    My stamped item
</li>
```

Please not that a lot of credits have to go to "Mikko Tikkanen, Zonear Ltd. ", beacuse it's a kind of an extension of his perfectMasonry plugin.

have fun!

Comment: +1 for your efforts..

Comment: another solution is set fixed position to masonry stamp element, check this out: `http://cdpn.io/xBcGw`